# Who are the two characters appearing in the background of superhero kids books?

Tags: comics, marvel, dc

Scott Snyder made an interesting discovery that people here might be able to answer: who are these two characters (see pics below) that keep reappearing in the background of both Marvel and DC kids books?

One has red hair, glasses and often facial hair, while the second has darker skin, dark hair and sideburns.

[image]

[image]

For the rest of the images (to avoid making this question massive in length), see [here](http://ifanboy.com/articles/scott-snyder-uncovers-bizarre-background-character-mystery/).

Comment: Probably an in-joke among illustrators, much like the overuse of the Wilhelm scream among movie sound editors.  Maybe it's an ironic response to a diversity mandate from above.

Comment: It's a massive conspiracy. They are stitching these two people into the comics to leak to the world about a massive government conspiracy to cover up the deaths of two DC illustrators.

Comment: Among the random theories people have tossed out, an homage to [Jerry Siegel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Siegel) and [Joe Shuster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Shuster) (creators of Superman, one of the first superheroes) seems most plausible...

Comment: It's official, this mystery has a [song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JslXTucgghg)

Comment: I see more of a resemblance in [Jack Kirby](http://www.panelsonpages.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/kirby-desk.jpg) and [Stan Lee](http://www.teako170.com/slee3.jpg).

Comment: Why don't you simply contact the artists? I don't know these books and who drew them, but many comic artists (you need the pencillers) have websites or are members of communities like deviantART. So just write them and ask them. Easy as pie.

Answer (score 10):

[Shuster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Shuster) and [Siegel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Siegel) (the original creators of Superman) seem like the most likely candidates.  The resemblance is pretty strong:

[image]

Here are Shuster and Siegel at a later age

[image]

Shuster and Siegel are something of folk heroes among comic creators, for having brought legal action to try to reclaim the copyright to the characters and universe they created.

Comment: Gould you at least add who these are, and why they'd be in there? I don't really see a resemblance.

Comment: They are the creators of Superman (see also last comment of Izkata in your original question)

Comment: @silvith that sort of information should be in the answer then. I don't get why they'd be in the series as cops though....and ginger? I still don't see a resemblance.

Comment: I edited the answer to better answer the question.  Thanks for the feedback, I'm new here :]

Comment: Good edit! I hope someone can come up with better photos, they still don't look like a match.

Comment: I think elempenguin might be right, they do look like Shuster and Siegel. I do not know if you have noticed but in the original Spider-Man trilogy with Tobey Maguire, Stan Lee appears in every movie, I would assume as a joke or as an easter egg for fans. It might be the case here.

Comment: In fact you can see they've drawn themselves with superman there....hmm....