# Have Shuster and Siegel ever cameoed in a comic?

Tags: comics, cameo

I'm trying to find out if Shuster and Siegel ever put themselves in one of their comics or if they've been cameoed by other artists/writers?

Either as themselves or as characters easily recognised as them.

Comment: related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/21864/3804

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Action comics #554](http://thecomicscode.weebly.com/action-comics-554.html), "What if Superman Didn't Exist?" -- there is, I believe, a homage, but it was not drawn by Schuster and Siegal, so I don't know if that would count as a cameo.